# Does anyone know if cloud run supports http/2 streaming while it does NOT support http1.1 streaming?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, webpieces

We have a streaming endpoint where data streams through our api.domain.com service to our backend.domain.com service and then as chunks are received in backend.domain.com, we write those chunks to the database.  In this way, we can ndjson a request into our servers and IT IS FAST, VERY FAST.

We were very very disappointed to find out the cloud-run firewalls for http1.1 at least (via curl) do NOT support streaming!!!!  curl is doing http2 to google cloud run firewall and google is by default hitting our servers with http1.1(for some reason though I saw an option to start in http2 mode that we have not tried).

What I mean, by they don't support streaming is that google does not send our servers a request UNTIL the whole request is received by them!!!(ie. not just headers, it needs to receive the entire body....this makes things very slow as opposed to streaming straight through firewall 1, cloud run service 1, firewall 2, cloud run service 2, database.

I am wondering if google's cloud run firewall by chance supports http/2 streaming and actually sends the request headers instead of waiting for the entire body.

I **realize google has body size limits**.......AND I **realize we respond to clients with 200OK before the entire body is receive**d (ie. we stream back while a request is being streamed in) sooooo, I am totally ok with google killing the connection if size limits are exceeded.

So my **second question** in this post is if they do support streaming, what will they do when size is exceeded since I will have already responded with 2000k at that point.

In this post, my definition of streaming is 'true streaming'.  You can stream a request into a system and that system can forward it to the next system and keep reading/forwarding and reading/forwarding rather than waiting for the whole request.  The google cloud run firewall is NOT MY definition of streaming since it does not pass through chunks it receives!  Our servers sends data as it receives it so if there are many hops, there is no impact thanks to webpieces webserver.

Comment: Google Cloud Run does not support your objective/definition. In front of Cloud Run is a proxy (GFE). The GFE does not support streaming. I recommend that you consider Google Compute Engine instead of a managed container service.

Comment: @JohnHanley check out wlhee 's answer below.  Sounds like it may be coming which will be awesome!!!

Comment: Yes, I am aware of Alpha features but I am under NDA for some of them. I am a Google GDE and I know the product managers. For my comments/answers, I prefer to recommend GA features and sometimes beta. Alpha features might change which is not good for long term answers.

Comment: ah, ok, cool, thanks @JohnHanley

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Cloud Run doesn't support HTTP/2 end-to-end to the serving instance.

Server-side streaming is in ALPHA. Not sure if it helps solving your problem. If it does, please fill out the following form to opt in, thanks!

https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfjwvwFYFFd2yqnV3m0zCe7ua_d6eWiB3WSvIVk50W0O9_mvQ/viewform

Comment: This is AWESOME!!  I signed up BUT is there a way to white list per server instance so I can whitelist staging first!  Is there a way to turn on/off? @wlhee